# How can I prevent packages from being installed from Debian contrib with exceptions?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I need to install a few packages from Debian `contrib`. (Specifically, ZFS-related packages.) However, I want to prevent myself from accidentally installing other packages from `contrib` without noticing. Therefore I would like to have a safelist of packages that can be freely installed from `contrib`, and block the rest.

I've searched the web and glanced over `apt_preferences(5)`, `apt.conf(5)`, and https://wiki.debian.org/AptConfiguration, but I didn't see anything that would let me fully specify the desired policy.

I'm currently on Debian stretch (oldstable as of this writing) but I have to upgrade to buster anyway, so I would happily take answers for that distribution too.

Comment: I haven't done it recently, but the standard instructions for enabling backports pretty much do this, don't they?

Comment: The linked answer shows how to do this for non-free, the same technique can be used for contrib.

Comment: @Michael nearly, but not quite: the default backports configuration (which is set by the repository) causes `apt` to prefer non-backports to backports, it doesn’t entirely prevent non-whitelisted backport installation.